# select2 changing value dynamically using jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-select2-4

I have searched many answers and tried them but i am not able to change the value of select2 dropdown dynamically using jquery.

I am using the ajax select2 getting the data remotely using json.

dropdown is working fine.

Here is what i have tried so far.

```
//UserGroupID is a variable contains the database value
var groupSelector = $("#EditSpeciality");
//1.
groupSelector.select2("val", {ID: userGroupID, TEXT: "Lorem Ipsum"});
//2.
groupSelector.val(userGroupID).trigger("change");
//3.
groupSelector.select2("val", {ID: userGroupID, TEXT: "Lorem Ipsum"});
//4.
groupSelector.val(userGroupID);
```

But none of them seems to be changing the dropdown value.

How to dynamically set the value..

Here is my HTML.

```
<select class="form-control select2" id="groupSelector" name="groupSelector" style="width: 100%;"></select>
```

=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=

**Update:**

Im using codeigniter MVC, i know this should not matter. but want to put everything on the table here.

The version of select2 is 4.0.0

JSON code that i am getting is from Controller through which select2 is populating the list.

Below is select2 Code.

```
function commonSelect2(selector,url,minInputLength,placeholder){
    selector.select2({
        minimumInputLength:minInputLength,
        placeholder:placeholder,
        ajax: {
            url: url,
            dataType: "json",
            delay: 250,
            data: function (params) {
                return {
                    q: params.term, // search term
                    page: params.page
                };
            },
            processResults: function (data) {
                return {
                    results: $.map(data, function(obj) {
                        return { id: obj.ID, text: obj.TEXT };
                    })
                };
            },
            cache: true
        },
        debug:false
    });
}
```

i call the above function like this to initilize the dropdown in page.

```
 // Speciality Selector for editing popup box
var SelectorSpeciality = $("#EditSpeciality");
var minInputLength = 0;
var placeholder = "Select Speciality";
var ConsultantSelectorURL = "' . base_url() . 'Admin/select_speciality";
commonSelect2(SelectorSpeciality,ConsultantSelectorURL,minInputLength,placeholder);
```

the function resides in some `.js` file under assets/js directory.

it helps me have the clean code and call the function whenever i want function.

i think we can fix it with initselection but i don't know how to fix it with **initselection** i also did tried googling it but had no luck..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As long as the option is appended to the list first, the second option will work (for select2 4.0)

```
$("#groupSelector").append ('<option value="' + userGroupID+ '">' + userGroupID+ '</option>')

groupSelector.val(userGroupID).trigger("change");
```

If you need the option to be selected this has to be done when appending,

```
$("#groupSelector").append ('<option selected="selected" value="' + userGroupID+ '">' + userGroupID+ '</option>')
```

and the trigger change isn't needed

Comment: The attribute `selected="selected"` was missing in my case. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The second method you tried works, you just set the value of the select and then trigger a `change` event so select2 picks up on it:

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $('select').select2();

  $('select').val(2).trigger('change');
  $('body').append('<p>Value is: ' + $('select').val() + '</p>');

  $('select').val(3).trigger('change');
  $('body').append('<p>Value is: ' + $('select').val() + '</p>');
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.0/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.0/js/select2.full.min.js"></script>

<select class="form-control select2" id="groupSelector" name="groupSelector" style="width: 100%;">
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Sir, My code has json data coming from the controller. and i am using select2 4.0.0.

and none of above methods worked out for me :(

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this it works in my case,

```
groupSelector.select2("val", {"id": userGroupID, text: "Lorem Ipsum"}, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at these three lines

`var SelectorSpeciality = $("#EditSpeciality");`

`groupSelector.val(userGroupID).trigger("change");`

```
<select class="form-control select2" id="groupSelector" name="groupSelector" style="width: 100%;"></select>`
```

Where did `#EditSpeciality` come from? As far as I see, the ID is meant to be `#groupSelector` on that specific select that you're trying to change. Not sure where the other ID came from. Swap

`var SelectorSpeciality = $("#EditSpeciality");`

To

`var SelectorSpeciality = $("#groupSelector");`

Then see if any of the other methods mentioned in your post work.